# how to capturing a desktop application and streaming it on a web app in realtime?

Tags: web-applications, video, video-streaming

I've been given a problem that I need some assistance from the SO community as I have no idea how to get a solution for my problem.

I have a project that needs to capture a desktop application in real time and stream them to users who can access the feed one they log into a web based application.

The streaming application needs to be able to capture the application only and not the entire desktop and be able to stream into a player that is hosted on the web applicaiton.  Similar to something that you would get from GotoWebinar or WebEx session.

I've looked at Flash Media Server but not sure if that would be suitable for my needs.

I suppose what ways are there to be able to achieve me goal? Would Flash Media server help or are there other technologies out there that would help in this senario?  I have a limited budget so the cheaper the solution the better.

I'm looking at developing the web app in PHP as that's the language I have most exposure to, however if I need to I am willing to develop the app in anything.

Cheers

Comment: Hmmmm. Well. To start, do you need to capture every change of state in the desktop app and stream that COS? Or to duplicate the logic of the desktop app (I hope not). Or to take a screenshot -- i.e., read the video memory -- of the desktop app every now and then and send that? IOW, what is the final consumer expecting? And will this final consumer be interacting with the desktop app? Or is he just monitoring or somehow managing the desktop app? Finally, what is the desktop app running under? I presume Win32, but maybe not.

Comment: I'm not looking at duplicating the application, I am trying to capture it's state, which can change a few times a second and not at regular intervals.  The best example I can give is like a airport departure screen or a trading screen. The consumer will be monitoring this feed and watching it in real time for information purposes.  The application is Win32 application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you have a limited budget, you can try Red5 - Open Source Flash Server [Red5 - Open Source Flash Server](http://www.red5.org) for server side. As for the client side, you can try software from Camtasia [Camtasia](http://www.techsmith.com/camtasia/), i remember it allow you to chose which application to record.